# Why is Node.js cluster.fork() not creating copies of my process on Windows 8?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

I'm experimenting with Node.js and whether or not it's a viable thing to suggest at my company. Being a beginner in it I'm trying to get a handle on Node without Express (or alternative yet) and the fact that an unhandled exception causes the whole process to shut down and basically takes me off the web seems like an issue. It very clearly says [not to use an uncaught exception handler](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) for the process to swallow errors.

Node.js's [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) seems like it would handle this nicely if I combine it with [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). In fact, the [domains recommend using them to just send out a 500](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors) and use clusters so that you can actually shut down the errored process.

I'm running Windows 8 Enterprise x64, and have [installed Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/) for my OS/architecture using the msi. I've got Node.js working and have been playing with it. However, when I run the sample code from the [cluster module tutorial](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) and then try to hit `http://localhost:8000` my browser can't connect. If I put a `console.log()` call in the else block it also never hits.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Tried this using what the defaults are from http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_settings
    // The values of these are undefined otherwise. Seems to make no difference.
    // Doesn't work if I remove this line either.
    cluster.settings = {
        execArgv: process.execArgv,
        exec: process.argv[1],
        args: process.argv.slice(2),
        silent: false
    };

    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
    console.log("This never hits.");
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("hello world\n");
    }).listen(8000);
}
```

Is this something I can fix on Windows 8 Enterprise x64? Is there an explanation as to why it isn't working?

Comment: Didn t play a lot with node.js for server, but I don t remember putting the listen in the cluster, you have numCPUs cluster listening together on port 8080...

Comment: May want to add a [cluster.on('listening')](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_listening) event (and others) to see if they are indeed listening.

Comment: Can you try the same on linux server? Windows support in node.js has always been kind of hackish (since nobody is using windows for servers anyway), so I wouldn't be surprised if this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @DrakaSAN The example code I used has multiple on port 8000, and the point of cluster is to share a port across multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this issue when debugging a nodejs app with Visual Studio on Windows 8.

Check if there are stale nodejs processes hanging around that may block the listening port. Surprisingly, there is no exception at listen() when the port is blocked by another process. I my case I manually killed the stale processes and the cluster worked as expected.